# VBA Syntax Highlighting

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

<sub>the below pertains to the flag `language: lang-vba`, which I have since been informed is not actually a flag, and for my use I should have been using `language: lang-vb`</sub>

VBA Code that uses conditional formatting, comments, date literals or open-ended strings is not highlighted correctly. For example,

[image: Prettify]

is not Highlighted like it is in the Microsoft Office Visual Basic Editor

[image: Original]

#### What is happening?

It would seem that instead of properly identifying `'` as the comment starting literal, it was incorrectly assigned to being a `char` literal (note that VBA does not support `char` literals in any fashion). It would seem that the `#` character was then assigned to being the comment starting literal, instead of the [Conditional Compilation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa240847(v=vs.60).aspx) literal.

Of significant not is that `#` also serves as the wrapping literal for declaring date type objects inline as seen in the example below

[image: Prettify_1]

Note that the `#12:00:01 AM#` is highlighted to indicate that it is commented out, rather than being represented like any other string or number literal

[image: Original_1]

Beyond this, VBA does not support multiline string literals of any form, and *in certain cases*  supports string literals without a terminating `"`. However, the current `Prettify.js` setup for VBA supports multiline strings, meaning that you an end up with code blocks that look like the one below on our site.

[image: Prettify_2]

<sup>Note that line 3 is included in the string highlighting, despite not being a string</sup>

#### What needs to be changed?

In the `Prettify.js` config,

1. The comment literal needs to be changed from `#` to `'` (which can be escaped by wrapping string)
2. The `'` char(?) literal needs to be removed, as VBA does not support chars
3. Removal of highlighting for multiline strings should be considered (if there are no characters, such as `,` or `)`,  expected after the end of a VBA string, VBA will autoformat to add a trailing `"` at the end of the line, and they are otherwise illegal strings)
4. It should be considered highlighting any, non-string, section of code which is wrapped in `[...]` (where `...` is some expression) in the same light red color as the string and number literals are, as this equivalent to a string which is wrapped in an `Application.Evaluate("...")` call

Comment: If anyone knows how who to talk to or what needs to be done, to get this correct, please leave a comment

Comment: [This may be helpful, especially the part about reporting bugs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/359104) - `Therefore, any bugs and feature requests regarding syntax highlighting cannot be handled by Stack Exchange and should be directed to the team behind Google Code Prettify.`

Comment: @StepHen, thanks for the link, I have submitted a issue ticket. ( https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues/502 )

Comment: Can you provide a link to the code in question?  My guess is that Prettify is inferring the code is in Python. If I put `<!-- Language: vba -->` before the code block, it highlights correctly.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic for the reason in the [comment above](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13670/vba-syntax-highlighting#comment48957_13670).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare (below snippets are live syntax highlighting, not screenshots):

## Default (meant for C-like languages)

```fake
Sub a()
#If n = 0 Then
Debug.Print "N=0"
#Else
Return 'This throws an error
#End If
End Sub
```

## Visual Basic

```vb
Sub a()
#If n = 0 Then
Debug.Print "N=0"
#Else
Return 'This throws an error
#End If
End Sub
```

In this case, you have to override the language hint, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/135945) for details.

(Note: I used a non-existent language hint to get the default language handler in the first case because this meta forum defaults to "none")